Reinstalling iOS on a phone and it is asking for a password but what password?
I did a factory reset to my glitchy iPhone and now want to reinstall from the backup. However, it asks me for a password. But what password? I tried my Apple ID password and my general MacBook unlock password, but no dice. What's it looking for here? Thanks!



When configuring backups of your iPhone on your Mac, you can optionally configure encryption for the backup, which will enable backing up some extra data from your device. If selected, you are asked to enter a password used to encrypt the backups.
This is the password you are being asked for. It has no relation to your Apple ID/etc unless you happened to choose the same password when setting it up.

About encrypted backups on your iPhone, iPad or iPod touch
If you can’t remember the password for your iPhone, iPad or iPod touch encrypted backup

If you don't remember the password, it might be in your Keychain:

Possible to find iPhone encrypted backup password in Keychain files?

